# Calculating the entropy of a specific attribute?

Tags: decision-tree, id3, entropy, information-gain

This is super simple but I'm learning about decision trees and the ID3 algorithm.  I found a website that's very helpful and I was following everything about entropy and information gain until I got to

[image: this point on the page.]

I don't understand how the entropy for each individual attribute (sunny, windy, rainy) is calculated--specifically, how p-sub-i is calculated.  It seems different than the way it is calculated for Entropy(S).  Can anyone explain the process behind this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split a node into two different child nodes, one method consists splitting the node according to the variable that can maximise your information gain. 
When you reach a pure leaf node, the information gain equals 0 (because you can't gain any information by splitting a node containing only one variable - `logic`).

In your example `Entropy(S) = 1.571` is your current entropy - the one you have before splitting. Let's call it `HBase`.
Then you compute the entropy depending on several splittable parameters. 
To get your Information Gain, you substract the entropy of your child nodes to `HBase` -> `gain = Hbase - child1NumRows/numOfRows*entropyChild1 - child2NumRows/numOfRows*entropyChild2`

```
def GetEntropy(dataSet):
    results = ResultsCounts(dataSet)
    h = 0.0   #h => entropy

    for i in results.keys():
        p = float(results[i]) / NbRows(dataSet)
        h = h - p * math.log2(p)
    return h

def GetInformationGain(dataSet, currentH, child1, child2):
    p = float(NbRows(child1))/NbRows(dataSet)
    gain = currentH - p*GetEntropy(child1) - (1 - p)*GetEntropy(child2)
    return gain
```

The objective is to get the best of all Information Gains!

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

Calc proportion that sunny represents on set S, i.e., |sunnyInstances| / |S| = 3/10 = 0.3.

Apply the entropy formula considering only sunny entropy.
Theres 3 sunny instances divided into 2 classes being 2 sunny related with Tennis and 1 related to Cinema. So the entropy formula for sunny gets something like this:
-2/3 log2(2/3) - 1/3 log2(1/3) = 0.918

And so on.